# nginx tries to use named location as real file path?

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to `proxy_pass` to an Apache2 instance using a named location, but Nginx tries to find the named location on disk?

Nginx Config:

```
root /var/www;

location / {
   try_files $uri @apache =404;
}


location @apache {
   proxy_intercept_errors on;
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}
```

Trying to access a file that doesn't exist should proxy_pass, but instead fails with a 404 and the log shows:

```
trying to use file: "@apache" "/var/www@apache"
```

It's a named location, so why is it trying to read it as a file path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The named location needs to appear last in `try_files`. You should not have anything past it (and indeed, it would never be reached anyway).

```
try_files $uri @apache;
```